# Aapt: error в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-style

В приложении обновляю библиотеку с yandex.кассы на yookassa.

в build.gradle в dependencies добавил:

```
implementation 'ru.yoo.sdk.kassa.payments:yookassa-android-sdk:5.0.3'
implementation "ru.yoo.sdk.auth:auth:1.0.39"
```

То есть всё, как указано в официальной документации.

При попытке запустить приложение выводит ошибку:

C:\Users\Alex.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\jetified-auth-1.0.39\AndroidManifest.xml:14:9-18:58: AAPT: error: resource style/Theme.Yoo (aka com.alex.example:style/Theme.Yoo) not found.

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Словил тоже самое, вылечилось так

Попросите у менеджера по подключению библиотеку ThreatMetrix Android SDK 5.4-73.aar. Создайте папку libs в модуле где подключаете sdk и добавьте туда файл ThreatMetrix Android SDK 5.4-73.aar. В build.gradle того же модуля в dependencies добавьте:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
}
```

если используется implementation "ru.yoo.sdk.auth:auth:1.0.39"

Попросите у менеджера по подключению библиотеку ui-lib-1.20.2.aar. Создайте папку libs в модуле где подключаете sdk и положите туда файл ui-lib-1.20.2.aar. В build.gradle того же модуля в dependencies добавьте:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё сработало!